# Windows 10 session manager failed to sign in

Tags: windows-10, login, session-manager

I use two accounts on my PC which I switch between them several times in a day.

But sometimes when switching accounts I get this popup window which says the following:

> The number of connections to this computer is limited and all connections are in use right now. Try connecting later or contact your system administrator.

Sometimes i get this window right after restarting my PC.

Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Start your PC normally and then try the following :

1.Press Windows Key + R and type **regedit** in Run dialog box to open Registry Editor. Click OK.

[image]

2.In the left pane of Registry Editor, navigate here:  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Setting

[image]

3.Moving on, highlight the Internet Settings key and come to its right pane. Then right click the Internet Settings and select New -> DWORD Value. Name the newly created DWORD (REG_DWORD) as MaxConnectionsPer1_0Server. Similarly create another registry DWORD and name it MaxConnectionsPerServer. Now, double click on anyone of them.

4.Finally, in the Edit DWORD Value box, select Decimal as Base and put the Value data equals to 10 (which is equivalent to a in Hexadecimal Base). Click OK. Similarly, change the Value data for another DWORD and put same value for it as well. Now close Registry Editor.

5.Restart your PC.

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer. Did all that, now will wait for that screen to appear :D One more question: can i see live somewhere how many sessions are used now?

Comment: you should be able to see this in the task manager